# Get a related class via signature java

Tags: java

I have a signature that involves a class like : "Lorg/demo/framework/FigureEnumeration;".

My question is that is there any way to get the class or the instance of the class by means of the signature? Because I want to check whether this class is Interface or not, plus I reach this signature from a field, I mean the type of a field is "FigureEnumeration", so I get the signature by using BcelField class.

I hope my question is quite clear for everyone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into reflection.

Comment: How exactly did you proceed to get such a display value (*"Lorg/demo/framework/FigureEnumeration;"*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `Class.forName`, from JavaDocs:

> For example, the following code fragment returns the
>        runtime `Class` descriptor for the class named
>        `java.lang.Thread`:
>
> `Class t = Class.forName("java.lang.Thread")`

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```java
String className = "Lorg/demo/framework/FigureEnumeration;";
```

You should first clean the name:

```java
// remove beginning chars that aren't a lowercased alpha char
// /!\ class must be in a package
className = className.replaceFirst("^[^a-z]+", "");
// remove ending chars that aren't an alpha char
className = className.replaceFirst("[^a-zA-Z]+$", "");
// replace any slash by a dot
className = className.replaceAll("/", ".");
```

Then, use reflection:

```java
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
```